# Let $f(x)$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. Prove that if $f(b)=0$, then $f(b^p)=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $f(x)$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. Prove that if $f(b)=0$, then $f(b^p)=0$.

Not sure how to proceed with this problem. I usually use Chegg, but Chegg doesn't have the solution for this problem.

This is what I have so far,

> "Notice that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field (Corollary of Thm 13.2), and
>   let $f(b)=0$ then $b$ is a zero of $f(x)$ so $(x-b)$ is a factor of
>   $f(x)$. Then $f(x)=(x-b)q(x)$ ($r(x)=0$ because $f(b)=0$."

Comment: The key to the problem is to remember a basic, unusual fact about raising things to the $p$-th power.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Perhaps a little Fermat can help you...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What is $f(b)^p$?${}{}{}$

Comment: Well, $f(b)^p$ would be $0$ since $f(b)=0$ and $0^p =0$. So... is that a QED?

Comment: @user131312 You have to relate $f(b)^p$ to $f(b^p)$. Have you ever raised a polynomial in $\Bbb F_p$ to the power of $p$ and seen what happens? Try it out.

Comment: @user131312: Yeah, what sea turtles says is what I'm hinting at. Certainly $f(b)^p=0^p=0$, but what does that say about $f(b^p)$?